# numpy np.where scan array once to get both sets of indices corresponding to T/F condition

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I have an array and I need to get the indices satisfying both where a condition is true, and where the same condition is false, e.g.:

```py
x = np.random.rand(100000000)
true_inds = np.where(x < 0.5)
false_inds = np.where(x >= 0.5)
```

In my use case `x` is quite large, this code is called inside a loop, and profiling has revealed that `np.where` is actually the bottleneck. I'm currently doing something analogous to the above code, which unnecessarily scans `x` twice to get the two sets of indices. Is it possible to get both `true_inds` and `false_inds` with just one scan of `x` without implementing a specialized replacement for `np.where` from scratch?

Comment: Do you absolutely need the indices themselves, or could a boolean “mask” work?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I need the indices

Comment: Doing it in one go would not reduce complexity though... So the bottle neck would really not be solved I would say... Is this a reduced example? What is the required execution time? and the current one? Are you testing this in production?

Comment: Can you reuse peallocated arrays (allocation outside the loop at max. size) and than reuse inside the loop? The allocation alone takes about 35% of runtime in a optimized implementation. If possible it would be recommendable to avoid this operation completely...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For operand sizes from about 1500 upwards splitting the result of a stable `argsort` appears a good solution (maybe two times faster, though towards very large sizes it appears to become less).

[image: ![enter image description here]

If you have `pythran` installed a more consistent speedup can be obtained (`numba` should be similar).

Notes:

1. It is important to use *stable* sort, i.e. `kind="stable"`, when omitted perfomance gets much worse on top of returned indices being unordered
2. I suspect this requires a fairly recent `numpy` version, since they just added new and type specific sort algorithms.
3. Some of the solutions plotted return indices in arbitrary order, but speedups gained if any are fairly small

Code to produce the plot, comment out the `pythran` related stuff if necessary:

```
from simple_benchmark import BenchmarkBuilder, MultiArgument
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
from biwhere_pthr import biwhere as use_pythran, \
    biwhere_halfordered as use_pythran_half, \
    biwhere_unordered as use_pythran_un

B = BenchmarkBuilder()

@B.add_function(alias="nonzero")
def use_nonzero(mask):
    return mask.nonzero()[0], (~mask).nonzero()[0]

@B.add_function(alias="argpartition")
def use_partition(mask):
    nf = mask.size - np.count_nonzero(mask)
    ft = mask.argpartition(nf)
    return ft[nf:],ft[:nf]

@B.add_function(alias="argsort")
def use_sort(mask):
    nf = mask.size - np.count_nonzero(mask)
    ft = mask.argsort()
    return ft[nf:],ft[:nf]

@B.add_function(alias="argsort stable")
def use_stable_sort(mask):
    nf = mask.size - np.count_nonzero(mask)
    ft = mask.argsort(kind="stable")
    return ft[nf:],ft[:nf]

@B.add_function(alias="sparse")
def use_sparse(mask):
    aux = csr_matrix((mask,mask,np.arange(mask.size+1)),(mask.size,2)).tocsc()
    return aux.indices[aux.indptr[1]:],aux.indices[:aux.indptr[1]]

B.add_function(alias="pythran")(use_pythran)
B.add_function(alias="pythran up down")(use_pythran_half)
B.add_function(alias="pythran unordered")(use_pythran_un)

@B.add_arguments('array size')
def argument_provider():
    for exp in range(8, 27):
        sz = int(2**exp)
        yield sz,np.random.randint(0,2,sz,dtype=bool)

# checks
for sz,mask in argument_provider():
    ref = use_nonzero(mask)
    for f in use_stable_sort,use_sparse,use_pythran:
        if not all(map(np.array_equal,f(mask),ref)):
            print(sz,f.__name__)
    for f in (use_partition,use_sort,use_pythran_un):
        if not all(map(np.array_equal,map(np.sort,f(mask)),ref)):
            print(sz,f.__name__)
    ht,hf = use_pythran_half(mask)
    if not all(map(np.array_equal,(ht[::-1],hf),ref)):
        print(sz,"use_pythran_half")

r = B.run()
r.plot(relative_to=use_nonzero)

import pylab
pylab.savefig('biwhere.png')
```

`pythran` module compile using `pythran -O3 :

```
import numpy as np

#pythran export biwhere(bool[:])
#pythran export biwhere_halfordered(bool[:])
#pythran export biwhere_unordered(bool[:])

def biwhere(mask):
    nt = np.count_nonzero(mask)
    f,t = np.empty(mask.size-nt,int),np.empty(nt,int)
    i = 0
    j = 0
    for k,m in enumerate(mask):
        if m:
            t[j] = k
            j += 1
        else:
            f[i] = k
            i += 1
    return t,f

def biwhere_halfordered(mask):
    ft = np.empty(mask.size,int)
    i = 0
    j = mask.size-1
    for k,m in enumerate(mask):
        if m:
            ft[j] = k
            j -= 1
        else:
            ft[i] = k
            i += 1
    return ft[i:],ft[:i]

def biwhere_unordered(mask):
    ft = np.empty(mask.size,int)
    i = 0
    j = mask.size-1
    while i<=j:
        if not mask[i]:
            ft[i] = i
            i += 1
        elif mask[j]:
            ft[j] = j
            j -= 1
        else:
            ft[i] = j
            ft[j] = i
            i += 1
            j -= 1
    return ft[i:],ft[:i]
```

Comment: So now who has time to add a benchmark using [RADIS](https://rapids.ai/index.html) on a GPU? My bet is that beats them all, for large arrays.

Answer (score 2):

First, something to note, from the [docs for `where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

> When only condition is provided, this function is a shorthand for np.asarray(condition).nonzero(). Using nonzero directly should be preferred, as it behaves correctly for subclasses.

---

This feels silly, but it's all I have for now unfortunately. It might be useful if you could share a bit more of your code, there's probably a better solution than this.

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.rand(10)
bool_mask = arr > 0.5

true_inds = bool_mask.nonzero()
false_inds = (~bool_mask).nonzero()
```

---

Here is what appears to be the source code relevant to the matter of performance and efficiency:

```
/*NUMPY_API
 * Where
 */
NPY_NO_EXPORT PyObject *
PyArray_Where(PyObject *condition, PyObject *x, PyObject *y)
{
    PyArrayObject *arr, *ax, *ay;
    PyObject *ret = NULL;

    arr = (PyArrayObject *)PyArray_FROM_O(condition);
    if (arr == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    if ((x == NULL) && (y == NULL)) {
        ret = PyArray_Nonzero(arr);
        Py_DECREF(arr);
        return ret;
    }
    if ((x == NULL) || (y == NULL)) {
        Py_DECREF(arr);
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError,
                "either both or neither of x and y should be given");
        return NULL;
    }
```

Comment: How different are `x >= 0.5` and `~bool_mask` in speed?

Comment: yeah, I think this solution actually requires even more scans of the array than the original

Comment: @hpaulj From a purely theoretical standpoint, `~bool_mask` should be much more efficient, no? Are you asking for the specific condition of `x >= 0.5`, or in general?

Comment: @EmmaStrubell That depends on the implementation of `where()`, I'm checking right now. In any case, it only does one pass to check the condition, instead of two, which should be the most demanding part.

Comment: @hpaulj Of course, the only difference is whether we evaluate the condition twice or simply flip a bool.

Comment: In the OP's example, flip the bool saves about 20% on time.

Comment: Using inverted mask was my first thought too, but on my machine (3.7 mac) both approaches take about the same time within error.  ...so this approach would have to be tested on the machine the OP wants to run on.

Comment: @Richard The performance is similar because the condition is extremely basic, it should be more efficient for complex cases.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile good point, in my case x < p (with 0 < p < 1) is always the condition, which is why I discounted this answer at first, but it would make a much bigger difference for more complex conditions which could be helpful for others, so I upvoted

Comment: If I am not mistaken, and if comparing to the chart for the chosen solution by OP, this “default” solution is only marginally worse than argsort, and in fact more efficient for small arrays, and really only can be beaten by using pythran or numba.

Comment: @fnl Oh yeah, I think the benchmarks were done because, well, it's pretty cool ;)